# Handling a python package name with hyphen in the setup() requires list

Tags: python, python-memcached

I depend on the package python-memcached but its name breaks the python naming conventions and consequently it breaks the setup function in core.py.

```
setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      requires = ['python-memcached','psycopg2']
      )
```

This breaks setup. How can I depend on the package?  Is it possible to rename it locally or create an alias?

Comment: It seems this only breaks distutils' `setup()`. Can you use setuptools' `setup()` intsead? It would use `install_requires=` instead of `requires=`.

Comment: @AdamKG That's a useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python-memcached`'s module name is `memcache`, hence use:

```
setup(name='foo',
  version='1.0',
  requires = ['memcache','psycopg2']
)
```

Hope that helps.

Another alternative would be to use `pylibmc` instead; more info on the latter it available here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibmc

Comment: I'm currently using the PyCharm evaluation. It says: "package requirement 'memcached' is not satisfied".  I can safely ignore this, however.

Comment: "memcached"? The module name is "memcache"... Feel free to accept the answer if it helped :)